# Odd-Even Mathematical Induction

Tags: induction

Simpler version of the Josephus problem. Circle of $n$ people, every second is removed

let $f(n)$ represent the last one from a circle of $n$ people

I've proved $f(1)=1$; $f(2n)= 2f(n) - 1$; $f(2n+1) = 2f(n) + 1$

Hypothesis: $f(2^m + l)=1+2l$, $2^m > l$

Can the proof be: $2^m + l$ is either $2n$ or $2n+1$?

when its even:

$f(2^m + l) = 2f((2^m + l)/2) - 1 = 2( 1 + l) -1$

Here can I use $f((2^m + l)/2)= 1 + l$? And similarly for when $2^m + l = 2n+1$? And why?

Do I need to have $f(2) = 1$ in the base case as well as $f(1) = 1$?

If viable, is this a type of induction?

And on a similar note. Instead of if $f(n)$, then prove $f(n+1)$; can you do if $f(n)$, then prove $f(2n)$ and $f(2n+1)$? If this is viable, what do you call this type of induction?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).